# C# Windows Forms How to Blank Out all other monitors

Tags: c#, windows, forms, multiple-monitors

I am building a log in form for a shared environment. 
This form will automatically pop up whenever a user logs in and asks for credentials (via RDP).

I discovered an issue that if the user has multiple monitors, they could disable the form pop up by accessing the Task Scheduler via the task view button on the taskbar. 
(Currently it will log a user out if they use any hot key navigation methods)

So I would like to have my form put up a blank screen on all other monitors so the user is forced to address the log in form.

I have found the System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens array but I am not sure how I can draw a rectangle on every monitor except where the form actually sits.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're on the wrong track here. There are so many possibilities to 'work around' your 'secure login' it's not even funny. I'd look into [replacing the shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher) or [kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app#set_up_assigned_access_using_imaging_and_configuration_designer) (if that's what you're trying to achieve) or explaining to us *why* you're trying to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is a shared development test environment VM. We are just trying to create a sign in form that logs who accessed it via RDP into a database. It is unlikely anyone accessing it will be doing anything malicious but the VM owner wants to see who is accessing it and from where. I just need a solution to the multiple monitors issue. Thanks.

Comment: Probably it is better to control who is able to reach this machine via RDP creating the appropriate permissions via the operating system

Comment: @Steve that is not an option at this moment. Its an azure based machine where all developers attempting to access this machine have a single log in. 
Is my question not possible to achieve?

Comment: _"Is my question not possible to achieve?"_ It is, but what you're not understanding is that it solves nothing. You're forcing a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it would solve nothing and also how this task can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so I thought I would share.

I created a new blank form (called monitorBlackOut), set it manual positioning and to be maximized.
In the main form I added the following code:

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length; i++)
            {
                int xPos = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Location.X;
                int yPos = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Location.Y;

                monitorBlackOut screen = new monitorBlackOut();
                screen.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
                screen.Show();
                screens.Add(screen);
            }
        }
```

Then when the user successfully logs in I can execute:

```
foreach(monitorBlackOut screen in screens)
      screen.Close();
```

Works exactly how its supposed to and will work on any number of monitors.